# How are body deformations modeled in Lagrangian mechanics?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

With rigid-body systems, we choose a finite number of generalized coordinates to model a system, i.e. a pendulum. However, I've read that deformable bodies like elastomers have "infinite" degrees of freedom. How does one write the Lagrange's equation for such systems? Is there an integral of infinitesimal volume?

Comment: You would need a field theory description, (classical) field theory is just (classical) mechanics for objects with infinite (continuous) degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, in continuum mechanics a body is discribed by a fixed orientable Riemannian manifold $B$ together with a (time-dependent) embedding in space, e.g. the $\mathbb{R}^3$: $$X_t:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3.$$ You could then define a free Lagrangian as a integral over the model body $B$: $$L(X)=\int_B \frac{1}{2} \rho \langle\partial_t X, \partial_t X\rangle dV$$ with $\rho:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ the density and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the scalar product of $\mathbb{R}^3$. This one could be seen as some kind of continuum limit of a system with $N$ free particles. Now you could add a potential function $U$ depending on the field $X$. For example if you want to model a (isotropic) rubber band a common choice would be $$U=-\frac{c}{2}g^{ij}\langle\partial_iX,\partial_jX\rangle$$ where $g^{ij}$ are the coefficients of the (co)metric on $B$ and $c$ is some quantity measuring how easy the body can be deformed. The Lagrangian than takes the form $$L(X)=\int_B\frac{1}{2}\left( \rho\langle\partial_t X,\partial_t X\rangle - g^{ij} \langle\partial_i X,\partial_j X\rangle \right).$$ Put in words, the potential $U$ is the deformation energy, see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_map). It measures how much the embedding $X$ deforms the geometry of $B$, thus the stress and strain of the body. The lowest energy configurations of $U$ are so-called harmonic maps, for example for a 1D rubber band these are giving a homogeneously strained straight line.

Anyway, to conclude, it is possible to treat contineous bodies in Lagrangian formulation by means of field theory. However, I don't know how the standard treatment looks like, the above is just a mixture of stuff I remember from continuum mechanics courses and imagination. The Euler-Lagrange equations are obtained in the [standard way done in field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_(field_theory)#Mathematical_formalism). I hope this helps answering your question, Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll read about these topics more.